# Using an Apple iMac as a monitor and tapping into the same iMac monitor’s core processor for network computing

Tags: cpu

Is it possible to use the same iMac that I am using as an external monitor for a Mac mini and be able to tap into the iMac monitor's processor to make a network computer?

In essence I want to boost the computing power of the Mac mini by not only using the iMac as a monitor but also try to access its processor to make some kind of network computer that could boost my mac mini in power also.

I feel the iMac’s processor is wasted if I only use the iMac as a monitor and not try to see if I can squeeze out any processing power it can offer at the same time.

I want to see if I can boost the output my Mac mini for 3D rendering, video processing, by tapping the iMac monitor's i7 core.

Comment: Nope. You can only do this if the software you plan on using to do any of this can use distributed systems for computing. It is not like you just plug in a cable and suddenly two CPUs work as one.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 A fun fact is that multi-core processing does work kinda like that. You know why Linux likes to display 4 penguins instead of 1, when it starts up on a 4-core processor? Because it's really 4 copies of Linux that co-operate with each other! But I don't think anyone's designed one that works on completely separate computers. Linux relies on all of the cores being connected to the same RAM.

Comment: That is True, I am looking into but having issues in finding software for Parallel processing or cluster type processing. There is also An external GPU (eGPU) processors that boost speed in video production. I am mostly trying to mimic eGPU if possible.

Comment: @user253751 Your point ab out multi-core CPUs is pedantic at best. Yes, I know what multi-core CPUs exist and how they work. “But I don't think anyone's designed one that works on completely separate computers.” Exactly. That only happens if there is software that is design to work across different computers: Also know as distributing computing.

Comment: that's why I said "a fun fact" and not "an answer"

Comment: @Humandude The use of eGPU (external GPUs) is entirely different than connecting to another PC completely and attempting to use the CPU on that system. For example, Final Cut Pro allows you to connect to multiple Final Cut Pro systems in a cluster to use to speed up video rendering. But that is only because Final Cut Pro is designed to do that. More info [here](https://fcp.co/final-cut-pro/articles/873-how-to-send-compressor-jobs-to-clusters-from-final-cut-pro-x-and-motion-5).

Comment: Depending on your video coding product, you can offload encoding to a remote "video processor". I believe DaVinci Resolve's recent versions have this ability. This solves half your problem without needing any weird custom remote processing stuff.